# How to create a plan in a function

Tags: drake-r-package

I'd like to use a function to create a drake plan.  See MWE:

```
plan_func <- function(param) {
  drake::drake_plan(
    myparam = param
  )
}
```

I would like

```
plan_func("a")
```

to give

```
# A tibble: 1 x 2
  target  command   
  <chr>   <expr_lst>
1 myparam "a"
```

but instead, it gives

```
> plan_func("a")
# A tibble: 1 x 2
  target  command   
  <chr>   <expr_lst>
1 myparam param
```

It feels like this is an NSE problem. Can someone give a friendly hint how to get this right?

My appreciation in advance!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`drake_plan()` supports [tidy evaluation](https://tidyeval.tidyverse.org/), so you can write `!!param` in the plan.

```r
library(drake)
plan_func <- function(param) {
  drake::drake_plan(
    myparam = !!param
  )
}
plan_func("a")
#> # A tibble: 1 x 2
#>   target  command   
#>   <chr>   <expr_lst>
#> 1 myparam "a"
```

<sup>Created on 2020-06-02 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v0.3.0)</sup>

Trickier situations like https://github.com/ropensci/drake/issues/1251 might require you to turn off the `tidy_eval` and `transform` arguments of `drake_plan()`.

## Edit

To splice multiple arguments into a function, use triple-bang (!!!) instead of bang-bang (!!):

```r
library(drake)

plan_func <- function(param) {
  drake_plan(
    myparam = f(!!param)
  )
}

  plan_func(c("a", "b"))
#> # A tibble: 1 x 2
#>   target  command       
#>   <chr>   <expr>        
#> 1 myparam f(c("a", "b"))

plan_func <- function(param) {
  drake_plan(
    myparam = f(!!!param)
  )
}

plan_func(c("a", "b"))
#> # A tibble: 1 x 2
#>   target  command    
#>   <chr>   <expr>     
#> 1 myparam f("a", "b")
```

<sup>Created on 2020-06-02 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v0.3.0)</sup>

Comment: Of course it does! Thanks for your quick answer, Will.

Comment: Note that if `param` is a vector (such as `c("a", "b")`), you need `myparam = c(!!param)`, else `drake::make(plan_func(c("a", "b")))` fails.

Comment: What about triple-bang, e.g. !!!param? That's the unquote-splice operator.

Comment: I had the same thought and tried triple-bang. I get `Error: Can't use "!!!" at top level.` for `drake::make(plan_func(c("a", "b")))`.

Comment: Just added an edit to my answer. You still might have to enclose the parameter in another function, but `!!!` opens up more flexibility.